# Installing additional packages (mayavi) in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, mayavi

There is a guide on the following website on how to add adittional packages. If I try to add the sci-kit package which is used as an example on the website it works, however when trying to install the mayavi package to Spyder it always fails.
Website: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Here you can see the output. By the way I'm trying this by using Anaconda. Please help

```
*(base) C:\Users\Viktor>conda create -n spyder-env -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.1.0
  latest version: 23.3.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.3.1



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Viktor\anaconda3\envs\spyder-env



Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate spyder-env
#


# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

# 


(base) C:\Users\Viktor>conda activate spyder-env

(spyder-env) C:\Users\Viktor>conda install spyder-kernels mayavi
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))



(spyder-env) C:\Users\Viktor>conda install -c anaconda spyder-kernels mayavi
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anaconda/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```